# How to make unknown Encoding work in SSMS?

Tags: sql, excel, database, encoding, ssms

I'm doing a personal project, and collected some data in Excel.
I exported it to xlsx, and several Hungarian actor names got encoded.

I want to work with elligible data in my database, so I want to decode it somehow, but I don't know how it was encoded, and upon looking through this matter online I found out that Excel doesn't exactly obey the user's preferences when choosing an encoding.

My question is, how can I find out what encoding it used, how can I decode it,
OR
How can I make SSMS understand the correct text?

Ex.: Ibolya OlĂˇh (Ibolya Oláh), IldikĂł BĂ©nyi (Ildikó Bényi)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "...some data in Excel, I exported to XLSX" - because Excel doesn't "export" its own native format...

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Ibolya Oláh, Ildikó Bényi'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1250')` returns `'Ibolya OlĂˇh, IldikĂł BĂ©nyi'`… Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].